# Mongoose nest pipelines lookups

Tags: mongoose

I simplified the relationships in the model

```
genres: {
    _books: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Books"}],
},
Publisher: {
    _genre: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Genre" }
    _books: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Books"}]
}
books: {
    _publishers: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Publisher"}]
}
```

Example

```
db = {
  "books": [
    {
      "_id": "5f3c47a859747bb370d98dc2",
      "isbn": "9781593275846",
      "title": "Eloquent JavaScript, Second Edition",
      "subtitle": "A Modern Introduction to Programming",
      "author": "Marijn Haverbeke",
      "published": "2014-12-14T00:00:00.000Z",
      "'publisher": "5f35578bf55f6cef9fd6193f",
      "pages": 472,
      "description": "JavaScript lies at the heart of almost every modern web application, from social apps to the newest browser-based games. Though simple for beginners to pick up and play with, JavaScript is a flexible, complex language that you can use to build full-scale applications.",
      "website": "http://eloquentjavascript.net/"
    },
    {
      "_id": "5f3c47b7ea05f3672b783042",
      "isbn": "9781449331818",
      "title": "Learning JavaScript Design Patterns",
      "subtitle": "A JavaScript and jQuery Developer's Guide",
      "author": "Addy Osmani",
      "published": "2012-07-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "publisher": "5f3557bd51bf64f398cb8853",
      "pages": 254,
      "description": "With Learning JavaScript Design Patterns, you'll learn how to write beautiful, structured, and maintainable JavaScript by applying classical and modern design patterns to the language. If you want to keep your code efficient, more manageable, and up-to-date with the latest best practices, this book is for you.",
      "website": "http://www.addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/"
    },
    {
      "_id": "5f3c47d422d49f143a146087",
      "isbn": "9781449365035",
      "title": "Speaking JavaScript",
      "subtitle": "An In-Depth Guide for Programmers",
      "author": "Axel Rauschmayer",
      "published": "2014-02-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "publisher": "5f3557bd51bf64f398cb8853",
      "pages": 460,
      "description": "Like it or not, JavaScript is everywhere these days-from browser to server to mobile-and now you, too, need to learn the language or dive deeper than you have. This concise book guides you into and through JavaScript, written by a veteran programmer who once found himself in the same position.",
      "website": "http://speakingjs.com/"
    },
    {
      "_id": "5f3c47ee95434d71f1e20a50",
      "isbn": "9781491950296",
      "title": "Programming JavaScript Applications",
      "subtitle": "Robust Web Architecture with Node, HTML5, and Modern JS Libraries",
      "author": "Eric Elliott",
      "published": "2014-07-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "publisher": "5f3557bd51bf64f398cb8853",
      "pages": 254,
      "description": "Take advantage of JavaScript's power to build robust web-scale or enterprise applications that are easy to extend and maintain. By applying the design patterns outlined in this practical book, experienced JavaScript developers will learn how to write flexible and resilient code that's easier-yes, easier-to work with as your code base grows.",
      "website": "http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000000262/index.html"
    },
    {
      "_id": "5f3c48000a78fe0c9dc10058",
      "title": "Understanding ECMAScript 6",
      "subtitle": "The Definitive Guide for JavaScript Developers",
      "author": "Nicholas C. Zakas",
      "published": "2016-09-03T00:00:00.000Z",
      "publisher": "No Starch Press",
      "pages": 352,
      "description": "ECMAScript 6 represents the biggest update to the core of JavaScript in the history of the language. In Understanding ECMAScript 6, expert developer Nicholas C. Zakas provides a complete guide to the object types, syntax, and other exciting changes that ECMAScript 6 brings to JavaScript.",
      "website": "https://leanpub.com/understandinges6/read"
    },
    {
      "_id": "5f3c480f8000f89a49f1586f",
      "isbn": "9781491904244",
      "title": "You Don't Know JS",
      "subtitle": "ES6 & Beyond",
      "author": "Kyle Simpson",
      "published": "2015-12-27T00:00:00.000Z",
      "publisher": "5f3557bd51bf64f398cb8853",
      "pages": 278,
      "description": "No matter how much experience you have with JavaScript, odds are you don’t fully understand the language. As part of the\"YouDon’tKnowJS\" series, this compact guide focuses on new features available in ECMAScript 6 (ES6), the latest version of the standard upon which JavaScript is built.",
      "website": "https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/es6%20&%20beyond"
    },
    {
      "_id": "5f3c483ae42cfd9bd3588fc8",
      "isbn": "9781449325862",
      "title": "Git Pocket Guide",
      "subtitle": "A Working Introduction",
      "author": "Richard E. Silverman",
      "published": "2013-08-02T00:00:00.000Z",
      "publisher": "5f3557bd51bf64f398cb8853",
      "pages": 234,
      "description": "This pocket guide is the perfect on-the-job companion to Git, the distributed version control system. It provides a compact, readable introduction to Git for new users, as well as a reference to common commands and procedures for those of you with Git experience.",
      "website": "http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000561/index.html"
    },
    {
      "_id": "5f3c487e9fcf0492cc27437f",
      "isbn": "9781449337711",
      "title": "Designing Evolvable Web APIs with ASP.NET",
      "subtitle": "Harnessing the Power of the Web",
      "author": "Glenn Block, et al.",
      "published": "2014-04-07T00:00:00.000Z",
      "publisher": "5f3557bd51bf64f398cb8853",
      "pages": 538,
      "description": "Design and build Web APIs for a broad range of clients—including browsers and mobile devices—that can adapt to change over time. This practical, hands-on guide takes you through the theory and tools you need to build evolvable HTTP services with Microsoft’s ASP.NET Web API framework. In the process, you’ll learn how design and implement a real-world Web API.",
      "website": "http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001708/index.html"
    }
  ],
  "publishers": [
    {
      "_id": "5f35578bf55f6cef9fd6193f",
      "name": "No Starch Press",
      "country": "USA",
      "foundeed": "1994"
    },
    {
      "_id": "5f3557bd51bf64f398cb8853",
      "name": "O'Reilly Media",
      "country": "USA",
      "foundeed": "1978"
    }
  ],
  "genres": [
      {
        "_id": "5f3c4365683f160563e88a3c",
        "title": "Programming",
        "_books": ["5f3c47a859747bb370d98dc2", "5f3c47b7ea05f3672b783042", "5f3c47d422d49f143a146087", "5f3c47ee95434d71f1e20a50", "5f3c48000a78fe0c9dc10058", "5f3c480f8000f89a49f1586f", "5f3c483ae42cfd9bd3588fc8"]
      },
      {
        "_id": "5f3c474497c127e67b191e2b",
        "title": "IT",
        "_books": ["5f3c483ae42cfd9bd3588fc8", "5f3c487e9fcf0492cc27437f"]
      }
  ]
}
```

I want to query two pipelines that get nested `genre -> publishers -> books`

```
db.publishers.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "books",
      as: "books",
      let: {
        publisherId: "$_id"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$publisher",
                "$$publisherId"
              ]
            }
          }
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
        from: "genres",
        as: "genres",
        let: {
          booksIds: "$_books"
        },
        pipeline: [
          {
            $match: {
              $expr: {
                $eq: [
                  "$books",
                  "$$booksIds"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ]  
      }
      }
    ],
  }
  }
])
```

This query is not working, the second pipeline does nothing

I am not sure how can I nest the second pipeline into the firstone, or even if I can do everything in one pipeline

I created [this link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Q_VNxnuvptS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what is the desired output but have a look at [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1q9uvggU6cq).

You can see the outer level are `genres`, followed by nested `publishers` with nested `books` within.

---

1. Firstly, I got all the genres.
2. Then I got the books and publishers with [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/).
3. I used [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) to separate publishers.
4. I added books with [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) to each publisher for filtering it later.
5. I used [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) to get relevant elements and [`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) to make an array of publishers.
6. Finally, I used [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) with [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) and [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) to get relevant books for each publisher.

---

```
db.genres.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "localField": "_books",
      "from": "books",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "books"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "localField": "books.publisher",
      "from": "publishers",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "publisher"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$publisher"
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "publisher.books": "$books"
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      genre: {
        $first: "$title"
      },
      publishers: {
        $addToSet: "$publisher"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "genre": 1,
      "publishers": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$publishers",
          "as": "pb",
          "in": {
            "_id": "$$pb._id",
            "name": "$$pb.name",
            "country": "$$pb.country",
            "foundeed": "$$pb.foundeed",
            "books": {
              "$map": {
                "input": {
                  "$filter": {
                    "input": "$$pb.books",
                    "as": "fb",
                    "cond": {
                      $eq: [
                        "$$fb.publisher",
                        "$$pb._id"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                },
                "as": "books",
                "in": "$$books"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

---

I am not quite sure why in one of your books there is no publisher id, but `"publisher": "No Starch Press"` instead. I assumed it has to be the `id` there.

Also, note that in your sample data there seems to be a mistake with a double quote `"'publisher"`.